# Bash - Pipe first line into variable and display the rest without using a temp file

Tags: json, bash, jq, aws-cli, tee

I receive some json that I process until it becomes just text lines. In the first line there's a value that I would like to keep in a variable and all the rest after the first line should be displayed with less or other utils.

Can I do this without using a temporary file?

The context is this:

```
aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name "$logGroup" --log-stream-name "$logStreamName" --limit "$logSize" |
 jq '{message:.nextForwardToken}, .events[] | .message' |
 sed 's/^"//g' | sed 's/"$//g'
```

In the first line there's the nextForwardToken that I want to put in the variable and all the rest is log messages.

The json looks like this:

```
{
"events": [
    {
        "timestamp": 1518081460955,
        "ingestionTime": 1518081462998,
        "message": "08.02.2018 09:17:40.955 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-138] INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=price-update]] launched with the following parameters: [{time=1518081460875, sku=N-W7ZLH9U737B|N-XIBH22XQE87|N-3EXIRFNYNW0|N-U19C031D640|N-6TQ1847FQE6|N-NF0XCNG0029|N-UJ3H0OZROCQ|N-W2JKJD4S6YP|N-VEMA4QVV3X1|N-F40J6P2VM01|N-VIT7YEAVYL2|N-PKLKX1PAUXC|N-VPAK74C75DP|N-C5BLYC5HQRI|N-GEIGFIBG6X2|N-R0V88ZYS10W|N-GQAF3DK7Y5Z|N-9EZ4FDDSQLC|N-U15C031D668|N-B8ELYSSFAVH}]"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1518081461095,
        "ingestionTime": 1518081462998,
        "message": "08.02.2018 09:17:41.095 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-138] INFO  o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [index salesprices]"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1518082421586,
        "ingestionTime": 1518082423001,
        "message": "08.02.2018 09:33:41.586 [upriceUpdateTaskExecutor-3] DEBUG e.u.d.a.j.d.b.StoredMasterDataReader - Reading page 1621"
    }
],
"nextBackwardToken": "b/33854347851370569899844322814554152895248902123886870536",
"nextForwardToken": "f/33854369274157730709515363051725446974398055862891970561"
}
```

I need to put in a variable this:

```
f/33854369274157730709515363051725446974398055862891970561
```

and display (or put in an other variable) the messages:

```
08.02.2018 09:17:40.955 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-138] INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=price-update]] launched with the following parameters: [{time=1518081460875, sku=N-W7ZLH9U737B|N-XIBH22XQE87|N-3EXIRFNYNW0|N-U19C031D640|N-6TQ1847FQE6|N-NF0XCNG0029|N-UJ3H0OZROCQ|N-W2JKJD4S6YP|N-VEMA4QVV3X1|N-F40J6P2VM01|N-VIT7YEAVYL2|N-PKLKX1PAUXC|N-VPAK74C75DP|N-C5BLYC5HQRI|N-GEIGFIBG6X2|N-R0V88ZYS10W|N-GQAF3DK7Y5Z|N-9EZ4FDDSQLC|N-U15C031D668|N-B8ELYSSFAVH}]
08.02.2018 09:17:41.095 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-138] INFO  o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [index salesprices]
08.02.2018 09:33:41.586 [upriceUpdateTaskExecutor-3] DEBUG e.u.d.a.j.d.b.StoredMasterDataReader - Reading page 1621
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you show the exact output needed?

Comment: Provide a valid working JSON removing these `...` characters

Comment: what do mean with *the rest after the first line should be displayed with less or other utils* and "and all the rest is log messages" ? Elaborate your question

Comment: I'll remove the ... characters, I added the wished output, thanks for the feedback

Comment: I'd consider using a different language. Related, why doe the token need to be in a variable? What are you doing to do with it once the variable is assigned?

Comment: @chepner I need this variable for the next query, there's a --next-token parameter. You get 10K lines of logs and need that parameter to get the next 10K lines. I don't think this is a language problem and text processing is very fast in bash.

Comment: No, text processing in `bash` is actually quite *slow*, and you have to run an external program to fetch each batch of log files. Another language would have an HTTP library (or specifically, an AWS library) to make each request within the same process.

Comment: @chepner so what is fast? do you know anything faster than grep and sed? they are c/c++ libraries, you can't go faster than that. aws-cli is python, it doesn't bring any overhead at all to call an external program. and if you use another language you will have the same speed, it's not the language that makes http faster...

Comment: The point is, you are spending time running *external* programs to do everything; running `sed` and `grep` and `aws` repeatedly is far slower than doing all the same operations in *one* program using libraries to do the same work.

Comment: @chepner your "far slower" means milliseconds. only the http call takes 2 seconds, not worth optimizing at all and not worth the overhead of using a language. It's like negotiating about cents if you buy a lamborghini. bash is portable, that's the advantage. in this context another language wouldn't solve my problem and wouldn't bring any significant improvement. stop trolling.

Comment: I'm not trolling; how much time have you spent looking for a cobbled-together solution for a problem you wouldn't have if you were using a language with proper library support for both HTTP requests and JSON?

Comment: @chepner we found the nick of Ken M on stackoverflow I guess, nice to meet you bro

Answer (score 2):

You might consider it a bit of trick, but you can use [`tee`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) to pipe all the output to stderr and fetch the one line you want for your variable with `head`:

```
var="$(command | tee /dev/stderr | head -n 1)"
```

Or you can solve this with a bit of scripting:

```
first=true
while read -r line; do
    if $first; then
        first=false
        var="$line"
    fi
    echo "$line"
done < <(command)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in storing the contents to variables, use `mapfile` or `read` on older `bash` versions.

Just using `read` to get the first line do. I've added `-r` flag to `jq` print output without quotes

```
read -r token < <(aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name "$logGroup" --log-stream-name "$logStreamName" --limit "$logSize" | jq -r '{message:.nextForwardToken}, .events[] | .message')
printf '%s\n' "$token"
```

Or using `mapfile`

```
mapfile -t output < <(aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name "$logGroup" --log-stream-name "$logStreamName" --limit "$logSize" | jq -r '{message:.nextForwardToken}, .events[] | .message')
```

and loop through the array. The first element will always contain the token-id you want.

```
printf '%s\n' "${output[0]}"
```

Rest of the elements can be iterated over,

```
for ((i=1; i<${#output[@]}; i++)); do
    printf '%s\n' "${output[i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Straightforwardly:

```
aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name "$logGroup" \
--log-stream-name "$logStreamName" --limit "$logSize" > /tmp/log_data
```

-- set `nextForwardToken` variable:

```
nextForwardToken=$(jq -r '.nextForwardToken' /tmp/log_data)
echo $nextForwardToken 
f/33854369274157730709515363051725446974398055862891970561
```

-- print all `message` items:

`jq -r '.events[].message' /tmp/log_data`

```
08.02.2018 09:17:40.955 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-138] INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=price-update]] launched with the following parameters: [{time=1518081460875, sku=N-W7ZLH9U737B|N-XIBH22XQE87|N-3EXIRFNYNW0|N-U19C031D640|N-6TQ1847FQE6|N-NF0XCNG0029|N-UJ3H0OZROCQ|N-W2JKJD4S6YP|N-VEMA4QVV3X1|N-F40J6P2VM01|N-VIT7YEAVYL2|N-PKLKX1PAUXC|N-VPAK74C75DP|N-C5BLYC5HQRI|N-GEIGFIBG6X2|N-R0V88ZYS10W|N-GQAF3DK7Y5Z|N-9EZ4FDDSQLC|N-U15C031D668|N-B8ELYSSFAVH}]    
08.02.2018 09:17:41.095 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-138] INFO  o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [index salesprices]
08.02.2018 09:33:41.586 [upriceUpdateTaskExecutor-3] DEBUG e.u.d.a.j.d.b.StoredMasterDataReader - Reading page 1621
```

Comment: but I explicitly asked not to use a tmp file ;)

Comment: and you could use mktemp to create the tmp file

Comment: @GismoRanas, once saving your json into tmp file you'll be able to process your json data in scalable way. Especially if there's a possibility to parse some other crucial data from the input json. Parsing json on the fly simultaneously distributing different portions into variables/ terminal/files is fragile tactic

Comment: yeah, but if I write not to use this solution it means I already know it, right?

Comment: literally - yes, conceptually - no. Willing to use wrong and non-scalable ways leads to fragile solutions. So, my solution doesn't pretend to be accepted by you - it's just an alternative approach for those who wants to go right way

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following meets the stated requirements, assuming a bash-like environment:

```
x=$(aws ... |
    tee >(jq -r '.events[] | .message' >&2) |
    jq .nextForwardToken) 2>&1
```

This makes the item of interest available as the shell variable $x.

Notice that the string manipulation using `sed` can be avoided by using the `-r` command-line option of jq.

#### Calling jq just once

```
x=$(aws ... |
 jq -r '.nextForwardToken, (.events[] | .message)' |
 tee >(tail -n +2 >&2) |
 head -n 1) 2>&1

echo "x=$x"
```